# How can I create a new Qt localisation for Qt itself?

Tags: qt, localization

Our application is localised and I have pulled in all the standard Qt_*.qm files as well so that my Qt dialogs are translated as much as possible.

However one of our distributors wants to add the Danish translation and its not in the standard Qt translation files.

How can I get Qt to create the file so I can send it off for translation?

Answer (score 1):

There is some information about translation of Qt itself:
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/internationalization.html#produce-translations

it's said that templates for qt translation (*.ts files) should be in the ${QTDIR}/translations directory. I can't see them in my Qt4 installation from official Ubuntu repository but I think they should be included in distributions provided by Nokia on official download page.

**Edit**

Idea how to generate new empty *.ts file for qt itself can be found in translations/translations.pri directory of qt sources. For Qt 4.6.3 it will be

```
lupdate -locations relative -no-ui-lines -I../include -I../include/Qt corelib gui-ts ../qt_my.ts
```

Comment: As I stated I already have the ones which are bundled with Qt, I am looking to create one which isn't.

Comment: You've mentioned that you have *.qm files from Qt distribution. You need to find *.ts files relevant to the version of Qt you are using then open them in Qt Linguist, translate and produce necessary *.qm files. I thought that your question is about where can you find those *.ts files. Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: I've just downloaded and extracted Qt sources for 4.6.3. There are *.ts files but only with translations. In this case you need to open copy of one of them and retranslate it into the language you need. I don't know if it's possible to just remove all existing translations from *.ts in one action in linguist.

Comment: @VestniK: Your edit works. A couple of points for others - you need to run it from the src directory of the qt source tree. Also "corelib gui-ts" is the module list and there are many other modules you might want to include or exclude. Look at translations.pri for the full potential list. Also on my RHEL6 system I had to run "lupdate-qt4" rather than "lupdate", presumably because I also had qt3.3 installed. Thanks.